# Get the latest Async query result only

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

So I am using a WCF service to make query and get result. The problem is if I make for example 5 back to back request to the service, I only intend to get the result of the final 5th query that I requested because the first 4 query is no longer valid. However, sometimes the service returns the 5th result before the 4th and the 3rd because it is a async callback. And my final result comes out to be 3rd or 4th instead of 5th. How do I tackle this problem? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
mSearchView.QueryTextChange +=  (s, e) =>
        {
            queryText = e.NewText;
            GetUserList(queryText, PageIndex);
        };



    private void GetUserList(string queryData, int PageIndex)
    {
        UserRepository.UserRepositoryClient client = new UserRepository.UserRepositoryClient(Config.Binding.BasicHttpBinding(),
                                                                            new EndpointAddress(Config.ServiceReferences.Repositories.UserRepositoryUrl)
                                                                        );
        using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(Global.Header.GetHeaderModern());
            client.QueryAsync(new UserRepository.UserQueryArgument
            {
                FullNameLastFirst = queryData,
                Pager = new UserRepository.QueryPager
                {
                    Index = PageIndex,
                    Size = 30,
                    ZeroIndexed = true
                }
            });

            client.QueryCompleted += client_QueryCompleted;
        }

    }

    void client_QueryCompleted(object sender, UserRepository.QueryCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Result.Data != null )
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => UpdateView(e.Result.Data.ToList()));
            }
            else
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => UpdateView(null));
            }
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Post your code. There's a bug, or your approach is entirely off track.

Comment: @usr I updated the post

Comment: You should consider moving to the `async Task` model rather than implementing callbacks. _[The task-based asynchronous pattern is the preferred way to implement asynchronous operations because it is the easiest and most straight forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701(v=vs.110).aspx)_

Comment: The webservice is completely away from me and not accessible or editable by me. The only way i can make a call and get a result is by the way I have done in the above code. Is there a way to come up with a logic to address the issue in the existing code?